# firefox: take screenshot programmatically

Tags: firefox

It's possible to take screenshots of web pages in Firefox using the developer toolbar. Is it possible to do this programmatically too, e.g., from the command line? I've tried with Selenium, but with no luck.

edit: I know it's possible to take screenshots using Selenium, but this only gets you the full screen. Using the developer toolbar in Firefox, one can use CSS selectors to select only parts of a page, which is what I want to do (and forgot to specify, sorry). What I've read online is that Selenium cannot access the developer toolbar because it's not part of the DOM.

Comment: Why don't you show the code you used when trying with Selenium? I know you can take screen shots with Selenium no problem. So probably just have a error in your code.